# Python - List how many numbers are correct in string

Tags: python-3.x

I have a variable called "number" which equals 1234

number = 1234

I want to have an input which asks for a number

user_input = input("")

I then want to check how many of the numbers the user got right so If I typed in 1235 it would reply 3

Comment: That is quite possible, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to count the same digit in the same position (i.e. input 4321 gets 0 right):

   ```
   number = "1234" # notice it is as string
   user_input = input("")
   len([a for a,b in zip(number, user_input) if a == b])
   ```
2. If you don't care about the position (i.e. input 4321 gets 4 right):

   ```
   number = sorted("1234") # notice it is as string
   user_input = sorted(input(""))
   len([a for a,b in zip(number, user_input) if a == b])
   ```

Notice that is not checking if the input contains character that aren't digits or the input length is longer than 4 digits.